# Remmina RDP - Issues with IP range on VPN

Tags: network-manager, vpn, ip, rdp, remmina

I've recently switched to ubuntu after many year using windows 10. After this switch, I couldn't remote connect to my work server (over VPN - OpenVPN). The error in Remmina was "Couldn't connect to host ..." and I also couldn't ping the server( ping error: Destination Host Unreachable).
So I've tried many different configurations and I've figured out the issue. My home IP uses 192.168.0.X and so does the work IP. After switching my home IP range to 192.168.1.X, it has connect smoothly.
So my question is: Is there anything I can configure to be able to connect to a server over VPN using the same IP range? Because I had no issues with that when connecting via Windows 10 and neither via Android.

Comment: We need more details. It is not clear if the problem is with RDP or VPN. What VPN protocol your work site uses. What exact errors do you get? Please edit your question.

Comment: I was using Open VPN. The error in Remmina was "Couldn't connect to host ..."
I guess it was a VPN issue, because I also couldn't ping the server. I suppose it was trying to ping the local 192.168.0.X and not the VPN 192.168.0.X.
(ping error: Destination Host Unreachable)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1400719/edit) and add all the new information. I don't know enough about VPN to tell you the exact problem with using `192.168.0.x` subnet for both your home network as well as the VPN office network.

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is not absolutely clear I suppose this is the answer:

Yes, you can run into problems when the Subnet of your LAN is the same as the Subnet of your vpn.

Best practice is to use different subnets. 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.1 have different subnets. 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2 have the same subnet.

In case both Subnets are the same you can specifically route your traffic for specific IP's to the VPN.

So in your wireguard config file you will write something like:

AllowedIPs = 192.168.1.1/32

The /32 means that only connections to 192.168.1.1 should be routed via your vpn and all other remain in your lan.

In case there exist devices in your LAN and your VPN that use the same IP it becomes even more complex.

- **So best you can do: use different subnets.**
- **Second best you can do: dont use equal IPs in LAN and VPN.**